# Sort Results in Mysql Asc

Tags: mysql

I have a database with this table:

1. Id (autogenerate)
2. Zipcode
3. Price
4. Adress
5. City
6. Date of sale(from 2017-2010)

The search is by zipcode
Now the ouput result is generate by mysql..I want the results order by date of sale:
 2017,2016,2015,2014...2010

My query is :

> //query the database
>       $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM land_data WHERE ZipCode LIKE '%$search%'LIMIT 0,30");

Thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY name ASC, other_field DESC`

Comment: Thanks, i will try!

Comment: Don't work, this is my query $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE ZipCode LIKE '%$search%'LIMIT 0,30");

Answer (score 2):

You need to add something like this to your SQL Query:

```
ORDER BY Name, Sale_Date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try!

Comment: Don't work, this is my query $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE ZipCode LIKE '%$search%'LIMIT 0,30");

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY name ASC, Sale_Date DESC
```

Comment: You don't need to add ASC as the default sorting value is ascending.

Comment: Thanks, i will try!

Comment: Don't work, this is my query $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE ZipCode LIKE '%$search%'LIMIT 0,30");

Comment: Try this: $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE ZipCode LIKE '%".$search."%' LIMIT 0,30"); In your query space is missing before LIMIT.